# How to create links in Dropdown List using PHP variables?

Tags: php, list, hyperlink, dropdown

I want to display the contents of a directory and insert their hyperlinks in a drop-down list. 
Here is my code.

```
<select>
    <?php
$dir = "/";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
        $target = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            $target=$target.$file;
            ?>
            <option value="<?php $target ?>"><?php $file ?></option>   
          <?php
         }    
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
?>
</select>
```

All I am getting is a blank list.

Comment: I would suggest not mixing the logic with the rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use classes to wrap your logic. :-)

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
final class Finder
{
    /** @var string */
    private $path;
    public function __construct(string $path)
    {
        $this->path = $path;
    }
    public function folderNames(): array
    {
        if (!is_dir($this->path)) {
            throw new \Exception('Path is not a directory');
        }
        if (!$directory = opendir($this->path)) {
            throw new \Exception('The directory can not be open');
        }
        $directories = [];
        while (($file = readdir($directory))) {
            if (is_dir($file)) {
                $directories[] = $file;
            }
        }
        return $directories;
    }
}
// Usage example:
$dropdown = new Finder($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$directories = $dropdown->folderNames();
echo '<select>';
foreach ($directories as $directory):
    echo "<option value=\"{$directory}\">{$directory}</option>";
endforeach;
echo '</select>';
```

Ideally you would have the part of “usage example” in another file. That file represents a template which receive a list of `$directories` and the template just need to render it.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't output the value:

```
<?php $target ?>
```

You need to either `echo` it or use the `=` shorthand.  For example:

```
<option value="<?php echo $target; ?>"><?php echo $file; ?></option>
```

or:

```
<option value="<?= $target ?>"><?= $file ?></option>
```

Comment: It worked, Now I can see a proper list but still can't see elements pointing to $target when I click on them.

Comment: @KunalAren: *"can't see elements pointing to $target"* - Can you elaborate on what you mean by that?

Comment: I want that each element ($file) should link to an address ($target) in drop-down list. Right now all elements are visible in the list but they are not linking to ($target).

Comment: @KunalAren: What do you mean by "linking to" in this case?  The code shown just renders a `<select>` element with its `<option>`s, there's no code shown for any form or any logic of what you do with that.  If you have some other code which isn't working in some other way, that sounds like the basis for another Stack Overflow question.